# Which one is Safer? Putting An "for" in a "Try" , or putting a "Try" in An "for"?

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, try-catch

I have this piece of code, I want to know do they work likewise and only their speed is different or they act totally different?

```
   try
   {
     for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
     {
         src.Samples[i].x = i;
         src.Samples[i].y = HR[i];
     }
   }
   catch{}
```

or

```
     for (int i = Start; i < End; i++)
     {
       try
       {
         src.Samples[i].x = i;
         src.Samples[i].y = HR[i];
       }
       catch
       {
         break;
       }
     }
```

Comment: Well your first isn't even valid, as you don't have a catch block. What exceptions are you expecting to catch, and what do you want to happen if they're thrown?

Comment: i didn't write the catch because of making question shorter i added it in the edit , i want the program to continue running when the "i" passes HR array's length

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just don't do that to start with - it's an abuse of exceptions, IMO. Write the code so it's safe *without* try/catch. If you don't know whether `HR` is long enough, use:

```
int cappedEnd = Math.Min(HR.Length, End);
for (int i = Start; i < cappedEnd; i++)
{
    src.Samples[i].x = i;
    src.Samples[i].y = HR[i];
}
```

(Use similar logic for `Start` if that might be invalid.)

If you feel you absolutely *have* to use try/catch for some reason, I'd catch the *exact* type you're expecting to be thrown, and put it on the outside of the loop - catching just to break feels even worse to me. And no, I wouldn't expect any significant performance difference either way.

Comment: thanks , and dear friends vote this answer up, despite being a simple answer i think it is smart . sorry i got low rep and can't vote this up

Answer (score 0):

The main difference would be that encapsulating your logic in a try statement would enable you to catch any errors/exceptions that might occur.

In your second listed example your could get an exception because of Start and or End being invalid values for some reason or the other causing a crash that you wouldn't catch.

Note that most code of that level is usually very simple and not very error prone.
Writing code that is free of exceptions is often the better approach though.

As stated in the comments you would need a catch block in your first example for it to work though.

Comment: As long as it managed to help you than I'm satisfied. Insightful questions are good to ask and will greatly improve your understanding of programming languages and concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I hopes you are a beginer(like me), so you expects an answer like this

I will tell another example.

### first code

```
try{
   foreach(file in files)
   {
     upload(file);
   }
} 
catch(Exception ex)
{
   handleException(ex);
}
```

### second code

```
  foreach(file in files)
   {
       try{
        upload(file);
       }
       catch(Exception ex)
       {
            handleException(ex);
       }
   }
```

on first code all file upload will stop when first one fails. In second if one failes handles exception there itself and code continues for next execution.

So in the example you given both seems like works in same way(since you are giving in break in catch block. Other wise both are differnet). So use try catch where it really requires handling.